# Ionic touch get text

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm building a dicionary function using the ionic framework. I would like this function: The user touches on a word, a popup window shows its definition.

How can I get the text touched by the user?

Comment: Please show some of your code here, whatever you tried till now.

Comment: I'm building a mobile website for the moment and considering using ionic for a mobile app because I can not get that function with mobile website. So no code yet. I'd just like to know if this is possible with ionic and then one tip on which function I can use is enough. Thanks@Apogee

Comment: ionic frame is precisely for cross-platform app development which comprises of ios, android, desktop, windows etc. And to show a popup window on tapping a text could be achieved by showing an alert by tapping on a button with transparent background. You may go through the official doc https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#alert